# Meaning of these conditions in the battery charger IC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

In this [battery charger](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) IC, below is a table.

[image]

My question is what does it mean when Vdd=Vbat & Vdd=Vin? I am not sure on what Vdd exactly is?
Going through the flowchart and the other table didn't provide much clarity.

Can someone explain me how to understand the highlighted conditions and in what scenarios do they occur?

In my testing, when the "No battery present" condition, both STAT pins should be in High-Z. But in that case, I am getting both are Low only. Any idea on why that happens too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does VDD indicate?

VDD is an internal voltage rail inside the charger IC.  It can be supplied from different places.  When the power supply (USB) is connected to the IN pin, then VDD it's supplied from the IN pin.  When the external supply is absent and the device is powered from the battery, then VDD is powered from the battery (V<sub>BAT</sub>).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, when you say, "When the external supply is absent and the device is powered from the battery", you mean - "The battery is connected between the Vbat pins & GND, as well as the battery is connected between the IN pin & GND" - Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Newbie  The battery is always connected to the Vbat pin (and never to the IN pin). When the charger charges the battery from the external supply, current flows out of the Vbat pin. When the device runs on the battery (without the external supply), the current flows from the battery back into the Vbat pin.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the outputs will be when those conditions are reached.

In a shutdown condition (VDD=IN) the outputs will be as follows:

- Stat1 will be high-Z (meaning the output will be high impedance like a large resistor with little current)
- Stat2 will be high-Z
- PG will be logic level low output voltage.

In a no input power present the outputs will be as follows:

- Stat1 will be high-Z
- Stat2 will be high-Z
- PG will be high-Z

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me what does Vdd indicate? The output voltage or input voltage? It is quite confusing

Comment: It means the VDD pin equals IN, meaning the VDD is tied to the IN pin or at the same level as the IN voltage. If it were at the VBAT voltage it would be the other shutdown condition

Comment: Thank you. Then Vdd=IN doesn't makes sense, right?

Comment: Depends on the circuit you have setup, in certain configurations this might happen.

Comment: Sorry I am still not clear

Comment: Please be specific, unclear on what?